# How to combine all ranges to range(0, 10) in python array?

Tags: python, for-loop, range

My for loop is not looping for all because my range was only range(0,1) so how to solve this issue.. Please help :( Thanks!

```
 def cleanString(newstring):
    newstring = newstring.replace("!", "")
    newstring = newstring.replace("@", "")
    newstring = newstring.replace("#", "")
    newstring = newstring.replace("$", "")
    newstring = newstring.replace("%", "")
    return newstring

    final_list = {'Category': categoryType, 'Notes': array}
    e = str(final_list)
    e1 = ''.join(e)
    c = cleanString(newstring=e1)
    arr_cat += [c]
    print(range(len(arr_cat))
    for i in range(len(arr_cat)):
        print(arr_cat[i])
```

When I print to check the range for the arr_cat that stores 10 data, the output of print(range(len(arr_cat)) is:

```
range(0, 1)
range(0, 1)
range(0, 1)
range(0, 1)
range(0, 1)
range(0, 1)
range(0, 1)
range(0, 1)
range(0, 1)
range(0, 1)
```

But I would like the expected output to be:

```
range(0, 1)
range(0, 2)
range(0, 3)
range(0, 4)
range(0, 5)
range(0, 6)
range(0, 7)
range(0, 8)
range(0, 9)
range(0, 10)
```

The output of variable c is:

```
1 I really love writing journals
2 The mat is very comfortable and I will buy it again likes
3 The mousepad is smooth
1 I really love writing journals
4 This pen is very special to me.
4 This pencil is very special to me.
5 Meaningful novels
4 It brights up my day like a lighter and makes me higher.
6 School foolscap
7 As soft as my heart.lovey
```

Comment: Please reformat your code, remove unnecessary code and create a minimal code that we can take and run ourselves and understand.

Comment: Also really try hard to think of good variable names, things like `value` or `e` make it tough for someone else to understand your intent. It requires other readers to store a mental dictionary of what your variables are. Instead of `value` use `categoryInformation` or something like that.

Comment: Where is `cleanString` defined? Looks like this is the one which creates the problem...

Comment: Print out the result of c. Let us know what the output is.

Comment: @Rafael I have added the result of c and I have already defined the cleanString as shown above

Comment: Your code (although with wrong indentation) looks like executes the `arr_cat += [c]` once. It will help if you format your code such that if we copy paste it on our computer we can run the script and see exactly the output you see. This might require to change some part of the code such that is simplified (e.g get rid of file reading and change it with some hard-coded values for example). If you change your code and provide a complete and minimal version of it, I am sure we will be able to help. As of now, there are a lot of gaps and unknowns.